# Apply certain stuff to multiple combobox

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox, styles

I am not sure if apply style would be a better title so I made it apply stuff. 
Below is certain piece of *xaml* which I use to remove the default arrow from `ComboBox` in my *WPF* application.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ConnTypes,Mode=OneTime, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">0</sys:Double>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Now I want to do the same thing to all the `ComboBox` without replicating the same piece of `<ComboBox.Resources>` for all the `ComboBox` . I want to define this(`<ComboBox.Resources>`) only once and this should be applied to all the `ComboBox`  in the window.

Can you please tell me a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add it in your `Window.Resources` via a `Style` without a `x:key` to thereby apply to all `ComboBox` control's in the `Window` implicitly

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Resources>
      <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">0</sys:Double>
    </Style.Resources>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**Sidenote:**

Do remember that your current approach "works" to hide the arrow of the `ComboBox`, but it does a bit more than that. So be aware of it incase you aren't already.

Setting the `SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey` to `0` will thereby "hide" the vertical scrollbar in the `ComboBox`'s `Popup` as well which uses the same system parameter for it's Width. So if that behavior is not desired, you're better off editing the `ComboBox` template and just set the "arrow" `Path` to have a `Transparent` Fill or just remove it all-together.

Comment: I agree to the use the `Template`. For the use construction like `<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">0</sys:Double>` earlier (< WPF 4.0) causing a memory leak. [Link1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981107) and [Link2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/14/memory-leak-hotfixes-for-wpf-3-5-sp1.aspx).